# How to add A TextView Dynamically in the ListView Items Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to add a TextView and Set it's value dynamically in the ListView and On click of the item i want to get the value of the item clicked .

I have a array

```
String[] statesList = {"listItem 1", "listItem 2", "listItem 3"};
```

My **TextView XML** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" 
    android:textSize="16sp" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    >
</TextView>
```

My **ListView XML**

```
 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="290dp"/>
```

Please help me how could i set those values in the array to the listview .i am new in android.Thanks

Comment: each row with a single textview?

Comment: yup each item will have only one textview that have text from the array

Comment: Instead of adding more textview everytime, it's a bad practice and consume alot of memory. Just use a single textview and add `\n` to the `text` everytime you want to add a new textview. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user2652394 same what u said i want to do this how could i do that please help me

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html

Comment: @GauravPandey each row with item like 1st row item listItem 1 second row listItem 2 and so on..?

Comment: @GauravPandey, `if(state == listItem 1) text = your_text else if(state == listItem 2) text = your_text + "\n" + your_second_line_text else if(state == listItem 3) text = your_text + "\n" + your_second_line_text + "\n" + your_third_line_text`. Hope this helps

Comment: in the listview item should be like item1 ,then second item2 so on

Comment: @GauravPandey list item meaning same row item 1 and item 2 or row 1 item 1 row2 item2 and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code i hope this is what u want

```
public void showstatesList() {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        String[] statesList = {"listItem 1", "listItem 2", "listItem 3"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, statesList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                int itemPosition     = position;
                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

//              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
//                .show();
              }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    ListView lv;
      String s="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        String value[]={"asda","Ansar","Nisam"};
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,value);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
//list item click
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                     s=s+("\n")+((String) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
                    tv.setText(s);
                }

            });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a ListView is an easy thing. All what you do is to create: 
-XML code : 
  --create a  element inside your **main XML file**, with its size, id attributes :

```
 <ListView 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/mainList"

                />
```

--another **XML file** , that you wanna make form of your List elements, like the from of your textView etc.. inside 'layout' file :

```
 elementsForm.xml :
```

if you want to make list of countries for example ,
 so create a LinearLayout that you will put text

form inside with "vertical" value to 'android:orientation' attribute 
      inside it create your TextView :

```
 <TextView 


   android : layout_width="match_parent"
   android : layout_height="wrap_content"
   android : textSize="25sp"
   android : id="@+id/texty"
    />
```

INSIDE YOUR JAVA FILE "**MainClass**" :

--create an inner class and let it inherits from ArrayAdapter
and create a constructor that takes 2 Parameters : the first Type is
 Context , the second Type is Data Type that you wanna display it and pass
 three values to the super constructor (ArrayAdapter):

1th : the context that your own class takes

2th : your own XML file that will consist and display the value like text View, audio View etc ...

3th : the array of values that we wanna display that our class takes as second parameter of its constructor

::

```
public class MyOwnInnerClass extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
public MyOwnInnerClass(Context context, String countries[]){
super(cotext , R.layout. , countries);
```

inside your class now override the getView() method that takes

```
@Override 
getView(int pos , View convert  , ViewGroup vg);
```

it consist three parameters that could provide with the element position and to make the elemenet inside our own XML file 
and parent as a reference to the parent View : 
Now go easy on this method and do ur purpose : 
inflate your List :

`LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());`

: we pass to the context of our outclass that will be used

```
 convert = li.inflate(parent , R.layout.elementsForm,false);
```

we pass to our View paramter of getView() method the inflate li object function and we pass to 3 values 
 the first :  our own XML file ID ; 
 the second one : parent the instance of ViewGroup ;
 the third one : we pass false ;

now we must getItems using getItem function pass to position parameter :

```
String st = getItem(position);
```

create TextView object and pass to your your xml using convert parameter:

```
TextView tv  = convert.findViewById(R.id.texty);
```

then set Text to your own text View :

```
tv.setText(st);
```

now don't forget the most important statement : the return Type method : return convert ;

--------*--------*-------------*----------*

here we go back to our "MainClass"  , we create instance of ListView , ListAdapter instances :

`ListView lv ;
ListAdapter la ;

` and inside the onCreate method :

```
 0)String [] countries = {"US" , "Canada","Egypt","China"};


 1) lv = findViewById(R.id.mainList);


 2) la = new MyOwnInnerClass(MainClass.this,countries);
```

0) we define a String array named countries contains four Values those we wanna display .

1) here we pass to lv object the id of our Element 'ListView' that will consist countries values with View Text ;

2) we passed an anonymous class that its constructor takes two parameters first context of the main class and the second the values we wanna display

the **last operation** to connect our ListView element with our own ListView Adapter 
 Class 'D' :

is declaring this function :

```
 lv.setAdapter(la);
```